# Kotlin Android extension can't resolve "text"

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

So I'm trying to get rid of "findViewById" and decided to add Kotlin Android extension to my project

Inside my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

In project level gradle.build:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
```

In my MainActivity:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

However, I still need `var editTextCity = editText_city.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_city)`

to resolve  `var city = editText_city.text.toString()`

seems like the extension is not working

Comment: Something in your example is off. You're calling `findViewById` for the view on the view itself. Also you don't use `editTextCity`. Did you maybe use the id more than once?

Comment: @tynn I meant `editTextCity.text.toString()` there. But I want to access directly to `editText_city.text.toString()` by using kotlin extensions (without findviewbyId)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: You should edit and update your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Also post your xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit classpath in the project level gradle.build to:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

and add this to your app level gradle.build as dependency:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

for edit text  you have to use :

```
 etEmail.setText(preferenceKeeper?.user?.email)
```

and if you want to get text from there then :

```
val valueFromEditText=etEmail.text.toString()
```

**And if you are using Kotlin extension then you can directly access by  id in your activity which is mention in you .xml**